# Passing data attribute from one to another element

Tags: javascript, html

I have two main html elements. First one is a group of options, the second is a `ul` where I display the content, like this:

```
<optgroup style="display:none;" class="groupOfOptions">
  <option value="15" data-upsell="presentation1">
    Item 1
  </option>
  <option value="3" data-upsell="presentation2">
    Item 2
  </option>
  <option value="5" data-upsell="presentation3">
    Item 3
  </option>
</optgroup>

<ul class="displayedList">
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="15" type="radio"> 
     Item 1         
   </label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="3" type="radio"> 
     Item 2         
   </label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="5" type="radio"> 
     Item 3         
   </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is to assign the `data-upsell-type` from the `optgroup` into the `ul` list. If a `li` item has the same text (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3) or `value` of input as some `option` element from the `optgroup`, then take the `data-upsell` from that `option` item and assign it to the specific `li` element.

This is what I tried:

```
var objWithData = document.querySelector('.groupOfOptions');
var listToModify = document.querySelector('.displayedList');
var currentText;
var getDataAttr;

for (var i = 0; i < objWithData.length; i++) {
  currentText = objWithData[i].text;
  getDataAttr = this.getAttribute('data-upsell');
  for (var x = 0; x < listToModify.length; i++) {
    if (listToModify[i].text == currentText) {
      listToModify[i].dataset.upsell = getDataAttr;
    }
  }
}
```

However, nothing happens and no errors are thrown for me to analyse. Could someone offer a look at this?

Comment: I agree this question is a good fit on Code Review. Please make sure to read their help center pages on how to write a question well, to make the most out of the site.

Comment: The code does not work.

Comment: [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): _"Returns the **first Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors, or `null` if no matches are found."_

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use some jQuery stuff in there? `.text` isn't a property of a HTML element (I think older versions of IE might have supported a `.text`, but it is not standard and doesn't work in other browsers). Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead. Also, in this context, the `this` in `this.getAttribute` refers to the global object (the window in the case of a browser), not the current item you are working on like in jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objWithData = document.getElementsByClassName('groupOfOptions')[0];
objWithData = objWithData.getElementsByTagName('option');
var listToModify = document.getElementsByClassName('displayedList')[0];
listToModify = listToModify.getElementsByTagName('li');

var listObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < listToModify.length; i++) {
  var el = listToModify[i];
  var text = el.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "").replace(/\\n/g).trim();
  var value = el.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  if(!listObj[text]){
    listObj[text] = [];
  }
  listObj[text].push(el);
  if(!listObj[value]){
    listObj[value] = [];
  }
  listObj[value].push(el);  
}

for (var i = 0; i < objWithData.length; i++) {

  var el = objWithData[i];
  var text = el.innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g).trim();
  var value = el.value;
  var data = el.getAttribute('data-upsell');
  if(listObj[text]){
    listObj[text].forEach(function(v){
      v.dataset.upsell = data;
    })
  }
  if(listObj[value]){
    listObj[value].forEach(function(v){
      v.dataset.upsell = v.dataset.upsell || data;
    })
  }
  
}
```

```html
<optgroup style="display:none;" class="groupOfOptions">
  <option value="15" data-upsell="presentation1">
    Item 1
  </option>
  <option value="3" data-upsell="presentation2">
    Item 2
  </option>
  <option value="5" data-upsell="presentation3">
    Item 3
  </option>
</optgroup>

<ul class="displayedList">
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="15" type="radio"> 
     Item 1         
   </label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="3" type="radio"> 
     Item 2         
   </label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="5" type="radio"> 
     Item 3         
   </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is loop over the options inside of `groupOfOptions` once, building a couple of look up objects. Then, loop over the `displayedList` `li` elements once, using the lookup objects to see if they need an upsell value:

```js
// the [...iterable] syntax is just converting the NodeList that querySelectorAll
// returns into an array using the ES6 spread operator. If you can't/don't want
// to use ES6 you could leave it a NodeList and loop over it with a normal
// for loop instead of .forEach like I will below.
//
// The selector .groupOfOptions [data-upsell] looks for all of the elements
// inside of groupOfOptions that have a data-upsell attribute, the option
// elements we want.
let optionNodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.groupOfOptions [data-upsell]')],
 textLookup = {},
 valueLookup = {};
 
 // build lookup tables
 optionNodes.forEach(function (el) {
   let text = el.textContent.trim(),
     upsell = el.dataset.upsell,
     value = el.value;
     
   textLookup[text] = upsell;
   valueLookup[value] = upsell;
 });
 
 // get the li elements inside of displayedList
 let listItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.displayedList li')];
 
 listItems.forEach(function (li) {
   let text = li.textContent.trim(),
     value = li.querySelector('input').value,
     textResult = textLookup[text],
     valueResult = valueLookup[value];
   // If we found an upsell for text or value
   if (textResult || valueResult) {
     // use the valueResult, fallback to the textResult if there was no valueResult
     li.dataset.upsell = valueResult || textResult;
     // Just for presentation purposes in this answer,
     // I'm also adding it to the title so you can mouse over
     // the list items and see what upsell value they got
     // without needing to inspect the DOM with dev tools.
     li.title = valueResult || textResult;
   }
   
 });
```

```html
<optgroup style="display:none;" class="groupOfOptions">
  <option value="15" data-upsell="presentation1">
    Item 1
  </option>
  <option value="3" data-upsell="presentation2">
    Item 2
  </option>
  <option value="5" data-upsell="presentation3">
    Item 3
  </option>
</optgroup>

<ul class="displayedList">
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="15" type="radio"> 
     Item 1         
   </label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="3" type="radio"> 
     Item 2         
   </label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
     <input value="5" type="radio"> 
     Item 3         
   </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- More about [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- I used [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var`. In this code it doesn't really matter, but it's good habit to use `let` most of the time. `let` is now [fair well supported](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let), even going back to IE11.